# Good short stories for learning German?

Tags: resource, literature

I'm trying to learn german and I think I would really benefit from reading short stories in german. Possibly with a translation. So do you know any good sites that can offer me that?

Comment: Do the short stories have to be (a) online and (b) available cost-free?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Yes that would be great. for me at least :) Or at least be available in a library!

Comment: I enjoyed reading [Klein Zaches, genannt Zinnober by E. T. A. Hoffmann](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/9200). Not sure if it's exactly *short*.

Comment: IMHO the stories by Kafka are an easy read, although it might not be your taste.

Comment: Big-list-questions are not a good fit for our question & answer site (see [FAQ]) as these will grow endlessly over time and will then be of little help for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it's a short story or not but the novel `Momo` by `Michael Ende` is a popular recommendation for German readers.

Comment: I am ignoring its pleading eyes for weeks now. It is shooting daggers at me from the bedside as we speak. :(

Answer (score 1):

Short stories, as well as other works of literature, are available for download at [Project Gutenberg DE](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/DE_Hauptseite). Check the Project's English pages to see whether English translations of them are also available.

When in a library, just ask the librarian.